# PHP unzip not working (MAMP)

Tags: php, upload, zip, unzip

I'm trying to upload and unzip a .zip file in my local MAMP server.
   Uploading is working great. But the file (named decomp.zip) doesn't upload, although I get the "woot!" echo.

And here is the relevant function in the test.php:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$FileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
   echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else { 
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
      echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
      $zip = new ZipArchive;
      $res = $zip->open('decomp.zip');
      if ($res === TRUE) {
         $zip->extractTo('/uploads/extracted/');
         $zip->close();
         echo 'woot!';
      } else {
        echo 'doh!';
      }
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
} 
?>
```

Here's the form:

```
    <form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea name="name" rows="2" cols="20"> </textarea >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload zip" name="submit">
    </form>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I checked the extracted folder and there are no files there

Comment: `uploads/` != `/uploads/`

Comment: `$res = $zip->open($target_file);`

Comment: ha, right. Thank you!